# Isothermal Process Question

Tags: thermodynamics

Question: During an isothermal process, 1,000 joules of heat are removed from a trapped gas. Determine the change in internal energy of the gas.

The change in internal energy is zero, but I do not understand why. Heat is energy, and if it is removed from the gas, shouldn't there be a decrease in the internal energy?

Answer (score 1):

No. For isothermal processes all changes in the heat are due to equal magnitude changes in the mechanical energy (work is being done by expanding the gas)

Answer (score 1):

Heat is transfered energy, yes. But it is not the only type. Work is also transfered energy.

If you remove a lot of energy as heat but the temperature stays the same, then you must be adding a lot of energy at the same time as well. For example as work. Otherwise the temperature and internal energy  would change.

The key here is to remember that not only heat but also work can alter the temperature.